# Is there a dyadic cube decomposition where edge length is comparable to L^2 averages?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Suppose I have some measurable function $f : B_1(0) \to [0,1)$, which is pointwise very small, i.e. $\|f\|_{\infty} << 1$.

I'm looking to construct some kind of dyadic cube decomposition or bounded overlap covering of the region $\{f > 0 \}$. I would like it to be the case that for a cube $Q$, we have 
$$
(\text{edge length of}\ Q)^2 \approx \frac{1}{|Q|}\int_Q f^2
$$

Can I do something like this? (The ''$\approx$'' should ideally mean within fixed dimensional constants of one another.)

---

The idea is that we want 
$$
\frac{1}{e(Q)^{n+2}}\int_Q f^2 
$$
to be basically the same on all cubes. Since $f$ is pointwise very small, we expect that for large cubes this quantity is very small. But as the cube size decreases, can we expect that this quantity *increases*? As an example, if the function $f$ is constant, $f \equiv c$ say, then
$$
\frac{1}{e(Q)^{n+2}}\int_Q f^2 = \frac{c^2}{e(Q)^2},
$$

Comment: That is not possible. If $f=c$ is constant, then the integral average over any cube equals to the constant $c^2$ which can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Hmm good point. I guess I know in fact more than I said.

Comment: Even with the modified version, if $f=0$, then it is still not possible.

Comment: I see... Maybe I'll try one more time before I give up